# How to get Text form EditBox AppWidgetManager .There has any way?

Tags: android, android-widget, widget

I have successfully implemented an EditText in a widget. By using following code.

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/edit_widget"
        style="@android:style/Widget.EditText"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="29dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:hint="Enter Name"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:nextFocusDown="@+id/btnSave"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:textSize="15sp" >
    </TextView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/widget_button"
        style="@style/normal_button_gray"
        android:layout_width="74dp"
        android:layout_height="29dp"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:minHeight="0dp"
        android:minWidth="0dp"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:paddingRight="0dp"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:text="@string/label_Add"
        android:textColorHint="@color/dark_gray"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
```

Following code use Class A with expend BroadcastReceiver

```
RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_demo);
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.ed_expersivecost, "");
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.txt_appname,context.getString(R.string.app_name));
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_button, MyWidgetProvider.buildButtonPendingIntent(context));
```

Following code  using Class B  expend  AppWidgetProvider

```
@Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
            int[] appWidgetIds) {

        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_demo);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_button, buildButtonPendingIntent(context));
        //how to get edittext value in here 
    }

    public static PendingIntent buildButtonPendingIntent(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction("com.connectingpixles.intent.action.Addamount");
        return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }
```

But not idea how to get text from EditBox Widget. Any one help can me?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getText() ?

Comment: I don't see the relationship between `Activity` and `AppWidgetManager` in this context?

Comment: @AkashSingh Take a look at my answer, I've updated it. The method I've described is used to share state among various components of android.

Comment: @AkashSingh if you don't have an idea, you need to ask for a clarification, not down vote along with your buddies.

Comment: @Downvoters He asked a different question first and then re edit his question, take a look at the two answers below is identical.

Comment: @DheeB This guy asked a different question at first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Not possible to Add Edit-box on Home-Widget. I have idea to open new Dialog (popup-window) like Edit-box Widget position on click on Home Widget.**

There has following method use for get click event of Home widget

```
    public class MyWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

         public static Intent intentForWidget(int appWidgetId, String specificIntent) {
        //action to perform
           }

         @Override
            public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager manager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        // modify after take action    
        }

         @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //There has called Pop-up window activity
        }


}
```

This answer can help u !!!! enjoy this .

Answer (score -3):

I assume your looking for EditText widget when you say EditBox.

```
EditText ed = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.your_edit_text_id);
String text = ed.getText();
```

Comment: I don't want to get text from Edittext in simple class Activity.. i want to get Text in Class appWidgetManager

Comment: @AkashSingh your original question didn't mention about appWidgetManager

Answer (score -3):

## Your XML says TextView

Here's the piece of code you are looking for. Copy paste should work for this XML.

```
TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_widget);
String text = tv.getText().toString();
```

PS: If you're doing this in an **activity** then `view.findViewById` becomes `findViewById`

**Update 1:**

OP, you still haven't provided proper information. What kind of class is AppWidgetManager? Anyway I'll take a stab at this.

You can store a reference to your `TextView` in your `Application Class`. You can update this reference when adding `TextView` to your `RemoveViews`. Use this reference to get the text from the `TextView`.

Another way is just use a `temp String` variable and create an `updateTextString` method in `class A` to update the `temp String`. And use the `temp String`

Comment: I don't want to get text from Edittext in simple class Activity.. i want to get Text in Class appWidgetManager

Comment: @AkashSingh could you show that particular class and also the class hierarchy? You might need to pass a reference. How to do that can only be said once one knows the what this class is doing and the class hierarchy.

Comment: I think the downvotes are uncalled for. Based on the information given by the OP, it looked like he wanted to get text from a TextView with an ID `edit_widget`. He needs to be clearer if he needed something else.